# How to properly save async/await axios response into variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Third party API can only handle one query string at a time. So I am trying to take multiple strings and split into array. Then I would map through the array, make async/await axios call and push each response object into an empty array.

With the code below, data doesn't seem to be stored at the end. My best guess is that I am not understanding how to use async/await function properly. Can anyone help me please?

```
app.get("/api/posts", (req, res) => {
  const tags = req.query.tags;
  const fetchData = [];

  const axiosCall = async tag => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://hatchways.io/api/assessment/blog/posts?tag=${tag}`
    );
    fetchData.push(response.data);
    //returns correct response object in an array
    console.log(fetchData);
  };

  tags.split(",").length > 1
    ? tags.split(",").map(tag => {
        axiosCall(tag);
      })
    : axiosCall(tags);

  //Returns empty array
  res.send(fetchData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since axiosCall is async, you need to wait for the promise(s) to resolve

like this

```
app.get("/api/posts", (req, res) => {
    const tags = req.query.tags;

    const axiosCall = async tag => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://hatchways.io/api/assessment/blog/posts?tag=${tag}`);
        return response.data;
    };

    Promise.all(tags.split(",").length > 1 ? tags.split(",").map(axiosCall) : [axiosCall(tags)])
    .then(fetchData => res.send(fetchData));
});
```

or using async/await everywhere

```
app.get("/api/posts", async (req, res) => {
    const tags = req.query.tags;

    const axiosCall = async tag => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://hatchways.io/api/assessment/blog/posts?tag=${tag}`);
        return response.data;
    };

    const fetchData = await Promise.all(tags.split(",").length > 1 ? tags.split(",").map(axiosCall) : [axiosCall(tags)]);
    res.send(fetchData);
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works! So without needing to initialize the empty array, it seems like inside the map array, where axiosCall functions is being called, return response.data is appending to the array? Also, at tags.split(",").map(axiosCall), it does not take any arguments and index value. Is that a short form of using it?

Comment: `tags.split(",").map(axiosCall)` is equivalent to `tags.split(",").map((tag, index, array) => axiosCall(tag, index, array))` - and since you ignore (don't declare so don't use) the 2nd and 3rd arguments in `axiosCall` function, there's no issue using the shorter notation

Comment: Thank you again.. Now I have a question on how would I be able to store them in a variable. Ultimately, I want to get multiple objects through multiple query strings and combine without duplication.

Comment: Sorry @JinmanKim - no idea what you mean since `fetchData ` **is** a variable that stored multiple objects through multiple query strings ... one for each tag